# Could not create plugin "AppPlugin"

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I am curretnly in the proccess of updating an old flutter project that I made about two years ago but ever time I try to run it it throws the same error saying that it could not create the plugin for "AppPlugin".

- Where:
  Build file 'android/app/build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.application'.
> Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
> > Could not generate a decorated class for type AppPlugin.
> > com/android/build/api/dsl/extension/AppExtension

Here is what my build.gradle file looks like

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new Exception("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.20"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```